# ASP.NET Web Application template missing in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

has anyone else dealt with this? My ultimate goal is to create a new empty web api project. I've been following tutorials and I've encountered the following issue:

My issue is that when I try to create a ASP.NET Web Application project in Visual Studio Pro 2012 I do not see that template as an option. I go to Installed --> Templates --> Visual C# --> Web

All I see is ASP.NET Empty Web Application. So I selected that and then expected the ASP.Net project window to pop up so that I could select "Web Api". However, that dialog never opened.

Does anyone know how/where I can get the ASP.NET Web Application template?

Answer (score 15):

I came across your question as I had the same problem. When I first installed Visual Studio I didn't tick the box to install the Web Components. Here is how I solved the issue:

1. Close all your instances of Visual Studio.
2. Run the Visual Studio Installer (I found mine in the Downloads folder still and was named "vs_professional.exe").
3. For VS 2013 a grey window appears similar to when first installing VS.
4. When prompted select "Modify" from the list of options.
5. Tick the list item which I think was named "Web Development" or something similar.
6. Click update.
7. Once the installer has finished running launch Visual Studio.

When selecting New Project in Visual Studio I can now see the required templates.

Comment: Old but still relevant: You don't need to download the installer again. Open "Programs and Features" from the control center, search for VisualStudio and hit "Modify" or "Change". From there you can continue from step 4.

Comment: For Step 5 in visual studio 2015 the name is "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools - Visual Studio 2015 - ENU" After that you will get the "Add folder and core references for" for MVC and Web API

Answer (score 10):

Try to select Framework 4.5.
The Framework 4.0 don't have :)

Jorge Rocha

Comment: Please add some more info to your answer, this looks more like a comment.

Comment: you saved my day.

Answer (score 9):

If you have ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application as an option under Web when you select it as a new project the project window pops up and you will be able to select Web API.

Answer (score 9):

kale909's solution worked for me. I just added pics here to make it more clear:
[image]
then here:
[image]