# RESTful Webservice with VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, rest, visual-studio-2015

I would like to create a RESTful webservice with writing C# and Visual Studio 2015

But in VS 2015  community edition I am missing the basic "Web" type in templates.

What is the recommended project type to create webservices now?

[image]

Comment: A WebAPI project is generally how RESTful services are created these days.

Comment: thx, but i can also not find WebAPI in the templates, which section is it in?

Comment: thx, but this "Web" section is just not there in my VS. i have only windows, android, cloud, extensibility, ios, silverlight,test, wcf and workflow.

Comment: i have added a screenshot to better understand

Comment: Re-run the installer. Most likely, the web templates didnt get installed. Steps are usually something on lines of http://stackoverflow.com/a/20442373/372871

Comment: @InSane that did it. thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to select this project:

> ASP.NET Web Application

[image]

When you click OK, you will get an additional window prompting for the exact type of the web application.

Select Web API there and you web service is ready.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you check the drop down in the top of the File => New Project box, make sure that .NET Framework version is at least 4.5. There should be a list that includes ASP .NET Web application. Clicking that should open another dialog box with the templates for creating a Web API solution

Comment: thx, but no matter what framework version i choose, there is nothing about web or webapi or asp.net

Answer (score 1):

You could create RESTful Services using WCF services.  And to use WebApi download and install the latest version of ASP.NET mvc.